# Why is a face appearing in Object mode but not Edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I have a face appearing in object mode which is not present in edit mode. Does anyone know why or what to do to remove it?

The screenshots show the problem clearly:

Edit mode showing no face:
[image: Edit mode showing no face]

Object mode showing a face:
[image: Object mode showing a face]

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: in EDIT MODE hit Alt+H to show hideen elements

Comment: They were indeed hidden... sorry for posting such a trivial question.

Comment: Even the trivial may seem difficult if you've never learned it. :)

Comment: Especially if you downloaded the model from someone else and didn't even know hiding faces was a feature that existed.